# Map JPA entity with relationships to a flat database table

Tags: java, jpa, spring-data-jpa, orm

Assume I have a simple database table which I cannot change its definition, but on the other hand I want to take advantage of object oriented programming to implement new APIs.

Here is an example of the postgresql DB table represantation:

```
create table message_request (
  id int primary key,
  recipient varchar(100) not null,
  message TEXT not null,
  parameters TEXT[],
  header_parameter varchar(100),
  button_parameter varchar(100),
  created_at timestamp not null
);
```

In the Java application I want to have an API with the following code:

MessageRequest.java

```
@Entity
public class MessageRequest {
  private Integer id;
  private LocalDateTime createdAt;
  private String recipient;
  private String message;
  @Type(ListArrayType.class)
  private List<String> parameters;
  private Header header;
  private Footer footer;
}
```

Header.java

```
public class Header {
  private String parameter;
}
```

Footer.java

```
public class Footer {
  private String buttonParameter;
}
```

I have no problems mapping the `MessageRequest` fields to the DB table, except for the `Header` and `Footer` classes which I want to map to the respective fields in the same table.

How is that possible?

Comment: use @Embedded annotation for Header and Footer class

Answer (score 0):

Annotation `@Embedded` worked like a charm.

MessageRequest.java

```
@Entity
public class MessageRequest {
  ...
  @Embedded
  private Header header;
  @Embedded
  private Footer footer;
}
```

Header.java

```
@Embeddable
public class Header {
  @Column(name = "header_parameter")
  private String parameter;
}
```

Footer.java

```
@Embeddable
public class Footer {
  @Column(name = "button_parameter")
  private String buttonParameter;
}
```